# Titanium Android module fails with "does not have a main jar file"

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-modules

I've created my own new Android Titanium module. The module build was successful and I have the artefact in the `dist` directory.

I've dropped the zip file inside my project, setup `tiapp.xml`, cleaned the project, but when running on the device I'm getting the red screen saying

```
Uncaught Error: Requested module not found: com.myproject.mymodule
```

I even tried extracting the zip manually and not let Studio do it. I cleaned the project several times.

Why wouldn't it find my module?

**EDIT**

I now notice a `WARN` message while compiling the app:

```
Module com.myproject.mymodule version 1.0.0 does not have a main jar file
```

I'm doing an `ant` build from eclipse and everything seems fine. I see the jar file created and present in the module directory inside my project.

Comment: Can you tell us the SDK version, Android version you are using to build the module? Also share the entry in your TiApp.xml for the module.

Comment: Did you try let the Studio package it and install it to your app project?

Answer (score 1):

Was facing the same error right now and I had a look at the place the error messages appears. It's searching for `module.manifest.name.toLowerCase() + '.jar'`. So have a look at the `modules/android/com.myproject.mymodule/1.0/` folder: the jar file should have the name that is inside the mainifest file (name tag)

The the warning should disappear and the module should be loaded correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing packaging the module in SDK location or in the particular project and see if things work. What I have always done is packaging the module in SDK location and add it in tiapp.xml of the project I want to use the module without facing any error like this.